# What is better approach to expand permission scopes of existing dropbox app that is in production

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a dropbox api app that exists in production for several years and a lot of people use it daily.

By the time my app was created it used only individual scopes an had access only to personal folders and files. But now I want to add additional functionality and support for team folders and files as well.

So what is the better approach to do this?

I currently choose between one of this:

- just add more scopes to an api app in app console and then inside my application manually call `/oauth2/authorize` using `scope` parameter to differ users that need only basic functionality from dropbox business users that need all of it
- leave existing api app with individual scopes as it is and create additional api app with expanded scopes and authorize users that need additional funtionality with this additional app.

The case is that it's impossible to authorize with basic account if app wants team_data.member so in the first case it is nesessary to manually use `scope` param.

And additional app will help me with separate usage statistics in dropbox app console.